# Remove a String from a list on a Redis server via a Java client using Jedi

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am pretty sure this is a stupid question, but how do I remove a String from a list on a Redis server via a Java client using Jedis?
I actually googled a little bit about this and my problem was, that the most things I found was about the Jedis from Star Wars. I know I could request the list from Redis, then remove in this local list the String, then delete the key of the list on the Redis server and then set the new list to the delete key, where the String is removed, but I am pretty sure that this is very inefficient and that there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call Redis' [`LREM`](http://redis.io/commands/lrem) from Jedis to do that. Note that this operation (`LREM`) is quite expensive in terms of complexity so perhaps you should consider a different data structure for your needs.